# Is there a way to control the blink speed of the notification LED on Nexus 4?

Tags: nexus-4, notification-led

On my Nexus 4, when I get a notification the LED blinks. However it is very slow so you can't notice it with a quick glance at the phone.

Is there a way to make the LED blink faster?

Comment: Try one of the many LED customization apps in the Play Store - https://play.google.com/store/search?q=led%20notification&c=apps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to control the blink speed in the OS itself. However, [Light Flow](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rageconsulting.android.lightflow) provides a plethora of options for colour, flash rate, etc. 
There are probably other equivalent apps too.